# Knockout css binding renders => class=" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 with KO 2.0

Tags: knockout.js

I am getting a strange style text with this code:

```
self.styleClass = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.isFollowing() ? "button" : "secondary button";
        });

      <button data-bind="text: followButtonText,click: toggleIsFollowing, css: styleClass"></button>
```

it renders:

```
<button data-bind="text: followButtonText,click: toggleIsFollowing, css: styleClass" class=" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12">Unfollow</button>
```

model.styleClass() renders fine in the console

Comment: I am not able to repro your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/s86Nb/1/ your code should work fine. Which browser and which KO version are you using?

Comment: @nemesv knockout-2.0.0.debug.js chrome and FF

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The semantic of the `css` binding has been changed from KO 2.1.0 to KO 2.2.0

From [Knockout 2.2.0 released](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/):

> We’ve also made some features work more like you might always have
>   thought they should work. For example, the css binding can now attach
>   programmatically-generated CSS class names to elements (previously, it
>   was limited to toggling predefined CSS class names).

So upgrade to **KO 2.2.1** and it will work fine.

If you cannot upgrade you can use the `attr` binding as a workaround:

```
<button data-bind="text: followButtonText, 
                   click: toggleIsFollowing,
                   attr:{ class: styleClass}" />
```

Demo [JSFiddle using KO 2.0.0 and attr binding](http://jsfiddle.net/JtJQz/1/)

Comment: Just a heads up--some versions of IE do not like `class` as a property name. I'd recommend wrapping it in quotation marks (`'class': styleClass'`)so that IE won't choke.