# dynamic classes + foreach + css + knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need to attach a dynamic class based on values in a foreach.

Here's the HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Tenancies">
    <tr data-bind="css: $parent.CurrentTenancy(date1, date2)">
        <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here's the JS:

```
self.CurrentTenancy = function(startDate, endDate) {
    var now = Models.Format.Date(new Date());

    if (now < startDate) {
        return "past";
    }

    if (now > endDate) {
        return "future";
    }

    return "current";
};
```

In the end I get the class attr with 0 1 2 3 as the classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout css binding renders => class=" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 with KO 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177163/knockout-css-binding-renders-class-0-1-2-3-4-5-6-with-ko-2-0)

Comment: You should upgrade your KO version.